# Makefile seemingly ignoring %.o wildcard

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, makefile

I am currently trying to compile the Julia Language interpreter on Snow Leopard—it has been giving me a heck of a time, but I think that I almost have got it down.

The latest hurdle has been the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `jltypes.o', needed by `/Users/arman/julia/usr/lib/libjulia-release.dylib'.  Stop.
```

The relevant parts of the makefile appear to be the following:

```
SRCS = \
jltypes gf ast builtins module codegen interpreter \
alloc dlload sys init task array dump toplevel jl_uv jlapi profile
...
OBJS = $(SRCS:%=%.o)
...
%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
    @$(PRINT_CC) $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(SHIPFLAGS) -DNDEBUG -c $< -o $@
%.do: %.c $(HEADERS)
    @$(PRINT_CC) $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
%.o: %.cpp $(HEADERS)
    @$(PRINT_CC) $(CXX) $(call exec,$(LLVM_CONFIG) --cxxflags) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(SHIPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
%.do: %.cpp $(HEADERS)
    @$(PRINT_CC) $(CXX) $(call exec,$(LLVM_CONFIG) --cxxflags) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
...
$(BUILD)/$(JL_LIBDIR)/libjulia-release.$(SHLIB_EXT): julia.expmap $(OBJS) flisp/libflisp.a support/libsupport.a $(LIBUV)
@$(PRINT_LINK) $(CXX) $(SHIPFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(RPATH_ORIGIN) -shared -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(SONAME)
$(INSTALL_NAME_CMD)libjulia-release.$(SHLIB_EXT) $@
```

Everything seems to be properly in place. As I understand it, when looking for the rule for `jltypes.o`, Make should use the `%.o` rule; however, clearly it cannot find a rule at all.

What makes me crazy is that it compiles just fine on Lion. I've compared the makefiles, their includes, and the Make program itself, but to no avail. This is my first intimate experience with makefiles, so thank you in advance for your patience and help and let me know if I need to include any other information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `%.o` rule.  There is a `%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)` (and its companion cpp) rule.  This means it can use it to build `jltypes.o` **from `jltypes.c` and `$(HEADERS)`** if those can be found.  Since the source file is likely to be there on both systems, I would suppose that the list of headers gets calculated differently (and wrongly).

Note that the cvs version of [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/) has just recently gotten a new option variable `MAKEPP_DEBUG` which causes it to write detailed info about just these things.  They can be viewed by the utility `makepplog`.

*There is much more to makepp.  Besides doing almost all that GNU make can, there are lots more useful things, and you can even extend your makefiles with some Perl programming.*

Comment: You were right on—it was a header issue. Thanks for the pointers about `makepp`; debugging features are always a big help for this sort of thing.